# Chart disappears when zooming

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When I zoom my Chart by X axle, graph disappears.Why this can happen?
Lib version - MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8zzk.png)

I used example LineChartTime. And edited `long hourMillis = 36000L;` in setData() function, and got problem with graph view.

UPDATED!!!

The problem become when time sampling smaller then 360000 millis or 6 minutes. When 1 hour like in example "LineChartTime" everything is ok. But if I reduce x value from 1451606400000L to 0 and make time sampling equal 1 millis everything is ok. So I think that main problem in float type of x value, that process incorrect big LONG values.

So, I found temporary solution.
When I get current time, I reduce it on 1451606400000L (2016 01.01 00:00) and draw not so big values, but also change Formatter string

```
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {

        private FormattedStringCache.Generic<Long, Date> mFormattedStringCache = new FormattedStringCache.Generic<>(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy dd MMM HH:mm"));

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            Long v = (long) value + 1451606400000L;
            return mFormattedStringCache.getFormattedValue(new Date(v), v);
        }
```

If someone have another solution please let me know.

Comment: Please transfer your solution to the answer box below, and then roll back your latest edit. We prefer not to squeeze answers into question posts, and we prefer not to have [solved] hacks in the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you zoom in, the library does not render values that are outside of the visible area. The algorithms here use the `float` type (probably for many good reasons), but this causes problems with "large" numbers.

`float` is internally a 32-bit IEEE 754, which means that it can represent only about 7 significant digits. Timestamps in milliseconds will get their last digits truncated (at least for the purposes of determining which lines to draw), so some of your lines wil disappear.

**Option 1:**
Use timestamps within range of `float` precision, or at least closer to it.

If you are plotting current data, substract a **stored** value of System.currentTimeMillis() from your timestamps and add the same value back when formatting, as you did in your own solution. If you can live with 1-second precision, divide your timestamps by 60000 and adjust the formatter accordingly.

**Option 2:** Patch the library to draw lines outside of the visible area.

A quick fix that will work if you don't have a large dataset is to render everything. For line charts, change the contents of the following 2 methods in `BarLineChartBase.java` near line 1280 like this:

```
public float getLowestVisibleX() {
    return mXAxis.mAxisMinimum;
}

public float getHighestVisibleX() {
    return mXAxis.mAxisMaximum;
}
```

This is probably wildly inefficient, which may or may not be an issue depending on your dataset size.